# Archive/delete shell script find command problem

Tags: linux, bash

Im trying to archive large number of .aud files in our Linux environment by doing this:

```
today=$(date +%Y-%m-%d)
cd /var/oracle/DEV/db/12.1/rdbms
if tar -zcvf /var/archived_audit_files/archive_auditLog"$today".tar.gz audit >> /var/oracle/auditFiles_archived_"$today".log; then
find audit/ -name '*.aud' -mtime +30 echo "Find went ok"
 echo "Archive DEV logs completed " | mail -s "Housekeeping DEV instance - $today" username@domain.com
else
 echo "Archive DEV logs failed!" | mail -s "Housekeeping DEV instance - $today" username@domain.com
```

And when executing this shell script I get error :

```
find: paths must precede expression: echo
Usage: find [-H] [-L] [-P] [-Olevel] [-D help|tree|search|stat|rates|opt|exec] [path...] [expression]
```

I wanted to test this find part before placing in this line for deleting :

```
 find audit/ -name "*.aud" -mtime +30 -exec rm {} \;
```

So idea behind all this that I receive mail when archive and delete operations are done, or some error occur.

Could you please tell me where I made mistake?

Comment: Maybe you mean `find audit/ -name '*.aud' -mtime +30 && echo "Find went ok"`
Note the `&&` there.

Comment: The `echo "Find went ok"` part of your `find` command is obviously wrong. Either replace it by `-exec echo "rm {}" \;` or, as suggested by @Cheatah, by `&& echo "Find went ok"`.

Comment: Thank you @Cheatah, command is executed as it should. Cheers

Comment: Hi again @Cheatah, if I may is it possible to redirect files that were deleted to a log file, i meant on this line : find audit/ -name "*.aud" -mtime +30 -exec rm {} \; ?